# Method constraint must be super of class generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How can I do the following?

I have a method which I need to say its generic type must be the super of the classes generic type.

Here is an example:

```
class Logger : ILogger, IStartable {}

///use
new FluentBuilder<Logger>().As<ILogger>().As<IStartable>();
```

This shows my intent, however does not work (as it is not syntactically incorrect):

```
public class FluentBuilder<TService> where TService : class
{
    public FluentBuilder<TService> As<TContract>() where TService : TContract
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still it's unclear to me; why would you need `As<Ilogger>` and `As<IStartable>` (at the same time)?

Comment: @Stefan updated my example, re the 2 As statements, it is an example consider Logger implements 2 interfaces (that we are interested in) and we want to describe that with the As<TContract>() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactlywhat you want, but maybe a step in the correct direction. You can implement your As method as extension method:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static FluentBuilder<TService> As<TService, TContract>(this FluentBuilder<TService> that) 
        where TContract : class 
        where TService : class, TContract
    {
        return that;
    }
}
```

The usage syntax is then:

`new FluentBuilder<Logger>().As<Logger, ILogger>().As<Logger, IStartable>();`